# DefaultCredentialsError when trying to collect Google default credentials for Google storage

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am attempting to upload a file to a Google cloud storage bucket from a service running on a Kubernetes pod. This requires authentication for the Google storage and so I have created a json authentication file from the console.

This json file is saved as a secret on my kubernetes environment and is referenced in the `deploy.yaml` through the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

The format appears like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xx",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"
}
```

And the following code of how I am handling this authentication:

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()


bucket_name = Config.STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Given that locally I have logged into gcloud, I am able to upload files when testing locally. However, when deployed to Kubernetes I get the following error:

```
 File "/storage.py", line 8, in <module>
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 308, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 166, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 92, in _load_credentials_from_file
    "File {} was not found.".format(filename)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File     {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xx",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"
}
 was not found.
```

I'm confused as it's referencing the file itself in the error so I am assuming it located it, but it does not recognize it as a valid service authentication file.

All help and pointers appreciated. :)

Comment: I would go through this tutorial https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python and grab the `credentials.json` from google developer console, then compare your two files and go from there.

Comment: For an easier future management, I recommend you to think about no key file usage when on are on Google Cloud Platform. For now, json key file should be use only for external platform (and I hope it will be soon no longer the case). Key file management is horrible: secure storage, rotation management, access management to this secure storage,... discard this when you can!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this code locally and then on kubernetes, to check if is a problem with your service_account.json file:

```
    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'service_account.json')
```

or [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python):

> If your application runs on Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, the App
>   Engine flexible environment, or Cloud Functions, you don't need to
>   create your own service account. Compute Engine includes a default
>   service account that is automatically created for you, and you can
>   assign a different service account, per-instance, if needed.

```
credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
# Create the client using the credentials and specifying a project ID.
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being that I had no set up the secret json key file as a volume mount in the deploy file.

Example of how I did it:

```
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /mnt/file_key/key.json
    .......

        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt/file_key
          name: file_key
          readOnly: true

........
      volumes:
      - name: file_key
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: file_key_secret
```